# Scan List of Computers for Windows Activation Status and Present Name, Status

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm attempting to use Powershell to do the following tasks, however I'm still pretty inexperienced and am looking for some help:

1. Scan our vCenter servers for all powered on Windows Machines (Complete).
2. Take list of VMs, and run the following command on every single machine:

   Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" } | where { $_.PartialProductKey } | Select Description, LicenseStatus
3. Output the information into a list that would read as: Machine Name | Description | License Status

Step 1 was already completed so that isn't an issue. I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to Invoke-Command on every single machine (tried using a foreach) and then display the data in a format described above. I know the command itself doesn't reflect the name of the machine being queried which is why I wanted to add it somehow.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: If you've already gor them in vlmware you can iterate the hosts and have them run the commands on the vms from vm powercli

Comment: Alternately you can invoke a commands on a list of compurers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have network access and valid credentials to connect the computers you can simply iterate the list of VMs with the `-ComputerName` Parameter and `-Credential` Parameter of `Get-WmiObject` like this:

```
$VMs = Get-VM
$Creds = Get-Credential ## Your Domain Admin Credentials
$Report = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$i = 1

foreach ($vm in $VMs)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green Processing $vm.name $i of $VMs.Count
    $WmiData = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $vm.Guest.HostName -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -Credential $Creds -Filter "Name like 'Windows%'" | 
    where { $_.PartialProductKey }  | Select Description, LicenseStatus
    $row = "" | Select VM,Hostname,Description,LicenseStatus
    $row.VM = $vm.Name
    $row.Hostname = $vm.Guest.HostName
    $row.Description = $WmiData.Description
    $row.LicenseStatus = $WmiData.LicenseStatus
    [void]$Report.Add($row)
    $i++
}
```

If network access is not available you can use the `PowerCli` [Invoke-VMScript](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Invoke-VMScript.html) to connect the VMs directly through the Hypervisor (ESX) without network connection, however VMware Tools must be installed on the VM

Comment: I don't see a need for the ArrayList object.

Comment: just a matter of performance, could be simple array `@()` as well...

Comment: You don't need an Array or an ArrayList object (or a simple array) to collect the items. Just output them.

Comment: Avshalom, thank you for this. This gets me most of the way to something that I am looking for. It appears I have some machines that I need to troubleshoot to figure out why they came back as blank. In my other Get-VM scripts, I previously had other commands to narrow down the search to only Windows VMs that were powered on.

I understand that I can't quite do that here since the script itself is pulling properties from Get-VM. Is there any other way I could narrow down those items?